# SortedList does not remove and adding items correctly

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-3.5, sortedlist

I encountered a problem with SortedList where 2 methods give 2 diffrent results.

```
//Item Data is one of this sortedList item
var itemPos = Items.IndexOfValue(ItemData);
Item item;
Items.TryGetValue(itemPos, out item);
```

The result is not that obvious. I will operate on numbers rather on abstracts letters to better ilustrate what is happening.

itemPos is getting set to 5. Ok! Next we try to get this item again form this index but no. It returns null. Ofcourse this is not happening immediately. This code is called before that happens.

```
    public void MoveItem(int indexFrom, int indexWhere)
    {
        Item itemToSawp;
        Items.TryGetValue(indexFrom, out itemToSawp);
        Items.Remove(indexFrom);
        Items.Add(indexWhere, itemToSawp);
    }
```

To move items on sorted list we have to remove and add item again. Ok! Debugging says that operation went wonderfully and my item have now index 5 i moved it from index 4. Where index 5 were empty before method MoveItem.

Or was it empty? Before that operation i had index 5 filled with stuff and i called simple Items.Remove(5);

But now happens what i described before.

Worth noting that this only is happening when i move item upwards in index, look from 4-5. When i move from 5-4 everything works correctly.

Do you have any idea what is going on over here? I'm using .NET 3.5

Full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static SortedList<int, ItemData> Items = new SortedList<int, ItemData>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Foo = new ItemData();
        Items.Add(0, Foo);
        Items.Add(1, new ItemData());
        Items.Remove(1);
        MoveItem(0, 1);
        var itemPos = Items.IndexOfValue(Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(itemPos);
        //Console should return 1 i think
        ItemData item;
        Items.TryGetValue(itemPos, out item);
    }

    public static void MoveItem(int indexFrom, int indexWhere)
    {
        ItemData itemToSawp;
        Items.TryGetValue(indexFrom, out itemToSawp);
        Items.Remove(indexFrom);
        Items.Add(indexWhere, itemToSawp);
    }

    class ItemData
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT: This is a bit confusing, but! Indexer (look at name of it :P) Take as argument KEY not INDEX. This is what get me confused and i mixedup everythig. So as Christoph said. Its better to use you own list you could use it as desire or read documentation deeply.

Comment: It would be easier to understand the problem if you could just provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, rather than describing bits.

Comment: Sure but problem is seems to be more complicated then that. I described it here somewhat general what is going on in my code and i have hoped that someone here would encouter it as well, and had a soution.

Comment: Unfortunately describing it in a general way doesn't help us reproduce it - whereas a short but complete example does. Your current "full code" starts with a method declaration or using directives - when I say a short but complete example, I mean something I can copy, paste, compile and run. We can do it from this, but there's no need for everyone who wants to help you to go to extra effort when you could have done it from the start.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to paste a few crusial but easy to fix lines. I will remember for future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are understanding the concept of a SortedList incorrectly. SortedLists are used when you have objects associated with keys, and the keys are sortable, and their order is relevant for performance, a certain algorithm or so. For example, think of a marathon, you could store Runner objects based on their finishing time in a SortedList. In any case, keep in mind the key is a sortable value, and each key is associated with an arbitrary value object.

Now, some problems that I observe in your code:

- In the first code box, line 2, you find the index of a value object. That defeats the purpose of using a SortedList because that operation is slow whereas looking up a value using a key is fast (via internal hashtable or so).
- In the first code box, line 4, you call TryGetValue. Look up the definition, the first parameter is a key, not an index within the SortedList. So this example is wrong from a semantic point of view.

Regarding moving items around in a SortedList (code box 2), that will always require removing the value object using the original key and then adding the value object with a different key (typically larger or smaller). But then again, I don't see why you would want to move items around in a SortedList anyway. The whole point is that you can simply add value objects that are associated with a sortable key, and the SortedList sorts all those objects automatically for you.

I have a feeling that you might want to consider a regular List object, or even just an array if size is fixed or limited. Then you get all your index semantics and can swap items around if that is what your algorithm really wants to do.

Edit: I just saw the complete code. My general recommendations above stand. The issue in your full example is that you are confusing keys with indexes. After MoveItem(0,1), the Foo object is registered with key 1, but since there is just one entry in the SortedList, it is at index 0, which you get with IndexOfValue (the slow operation). Then when you do a TryGetValue, you really look up an entry with key 0, which doesn't exist. You incorrectly assumed TryGetValue would take an index as parameter.

Comment: I used sorted list for purpose of having indexes and haveing it always sorted. Sorted list also sorts items if index doesnt exists and can extend. Thats why i used it in my project. I can change it, but i would like to know why such operations dont work.

Comment: Just added to my answer, after "Edit:..."

Comment: Oh. You are right! I overlooked SortedList funcionality! As you said i will try to implement my own list if its look like that.

Answer (score 2):

You're confused between the *key* of the entry and the *index* of the entry. Your `MoveItem` method just changes the key associated with a value (by removing the old entry and creating a new entry). After these lines:

```
Items.Add(0, Foo);
Items.Add(1, new ItemData());
Items.Remove(1);
```

... there will only be a single entry in the collection, and `MoveItem` will remove/add so that doesn't change the count. Therefore `IndexOfValue` can *only* return 0 (or -1 if it's not found).

To get 1, you'd want to find the *key* associated with the value, not the index. For example:

```
int index = Items.IndexOfValue(Foo);
int key = Items.Keys[index];
Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}", key); // Prints 1
```

Note that `TryGetValue` takes the *key*, not the index - so this line:

```
Items.TryGetValue(itemPos, out item);
```

... would be a very odd one.

All of this is easier to see if you use a different key type, e.g. a string. Then you can't get confused between keys and indexes, because the types are different and the compiler won't let you use one where you meant the other.

Comment: Yes! Thats is correct now i understood what its going, but Christoph was faster, anyway have a Up.